# How to decrypt MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 encrypted string in ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, encryption, mcrypt

My web service is encrypting data in codigniter using

```
base64_encode($this->mcrypt_encode($string,$key));
```

I am using Cipher name MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 and Cipher Mode  MCRYPT_MODE_CBC.

This Web service is called in ionic project. Which library I can use in ionic 3 to decrypt this ?